# Error doing recursion in python using lists

Tags: python, list, recursion, integer

Write a recursive function addElements that returns the sum of the elements in a list.
For example, addElements([2,1,3]) gives 6.

```
def addElements(s):
    if s == []:
        return 0
    else:
        s[0] + addElements(s[1:])
        return s
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

getting this error,
Any help would be good thanks :)

Comment: Heh, you could just cheat and do `sum(s)`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in these lines.

```
s[0] + addElements(s[1:])
return s
```

You are finding the sum of two elements, ignoring them and returning the list. When you simply return `s`, previous `addElements(s[1:])` call will get the `s[1:]` and you will be trying to

```
s[0] + s[1:]
```

where `s[0]` would be the first element in the list, and `s[1:]` would be rest of the list. That is why you are getting that error.

What you should have done is

```
return s[0] + addElements(s[1:])
```

So, your recursion will become like this

```
addElements([2, 1, 3])
       ||
2 + (addElements([1, 3]))
       ||
2 + (1 + (addElements([3])))
       ||
2 + (1 + (3 + (addElements([]))))
       ||
2 + (1 + (3 + (0)))
       ||
2 + (1 + (3))
       ||
2 + (4)
       ||
6 # Your answer
```

Comment: @user3464959 Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with recursion. The first element of `s` is obviously an integer and you are trying to add a list to an int as the error stated.

Maybe you meant:

```
def addElements(s):
    if not s: return 0
    return s[0] + addElements(s[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see the different exit points of the function and see what types are the values you return.

If you see this alternative code:

```
def addElements(s):
    return 0 if s == [] else s[0] + addElements(s[1:])
```

you can see the two alternatives being 0 or s[0] (which should yield an integer in your flat list) + addElements(s[1:]) (which should yield another call to itself (having the cut condition an integer as return value), or an integer).

Also I'd suggest you use `sum(s)` instead of your custom function, since sum() is native and compiled, and will be quicker.